# Handle item click of dynamic Expandable list in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have dynamic lists inside the dynamic list, My need is to save option with their attributes. I tried so many ways to show drop down of attributes for every option but `DropDownMenuitem` Widgets does not handle dynamic list in the stable version of flutter, so I have to use Expandable List for this purpose. When I select an attribute of an option then how can I reflect the selection of a particular option in the header or how can I save the selection of dynamic attribute

This is how i build my list

```
ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: opAtrrList.length>0?opAtrrList.length:0,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  return ExpansionTile(
                    title:optionTitle(width,height,opAtrrList[i].groupname,selectedAttr),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Column(
                        children: _buildExpandableContent(opAtrrList[i]),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
```

This is my expandable item **`Attribute selectedAttr;`**

```
_buildExpandableContent(OptionAttribute oa) {
      List<Widget> columnContent = [];
      for(int i=0;i<oa.attrlist.length;i++){
        columnContent.add(
          new ListTile(
            onTap: (){
              setState(() {
                selectedAttr=oa.attrlist[i];
              });
            },
            title: new Text(oa.attrlist[i].attributename, style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'medium',color: MyColors.colorPrimaryDark)),
          ),
        );
      }
      return columnContent;
    }
```

Please see the below gif.

[image]